# invisible PopupWindow delays keyboard accessibility (EditText)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

does anyone understand why when I click on a non-empty EditText, my keyboard stop responding for couple of seconds?

Here's the flow with Logcat info:

- if I click on an empty EditText. Everything is fine. I can start typing. Nothing weird in the Logcat.
- if I click on an non-empty EditText, I'm not able to type on my keyboard for 5 sec (approx.) In this case, the Logcat shows:

--

```
D/ViewRootImpl@91ef75b[PopupWindow:4f1ca58]: setView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{cef3bf8 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} TM=true MM=false
D/ViewRootImpl@91ef75b[PopupWindow:4f1ca58]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
D/ViewRootImpl@91ef75b[PopupWindow:4f1ca58]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[80,1080][1160,3300] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 535477391360} changed=tru
```

And after a few seconds I get:

```
D/ViewRootImpl@2169ec9[PopupWindow:f857c1b]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputEventReceiver: channel '9df2d1e PopupWindow:f857c1b (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
channel '9df2d1e PopupWindow:f857c1b (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver.
```

and then I can start typing again.

I have no clue from where this `PopupWindow` is coming from and why it only fires up in the `Logcat` when the `EditText` is not empty.

*PS: I also noticed when I do a long press on the `EditText` to open the popup Menu (copy/paste/...etc), the menu has a weird margin/padding and texts are not centered.*

Here's the code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/paddingLarge">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        style="@style/SignUpEditText"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        style="@style/SignUpEditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/paddingSmall"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    <com.tremend.indieframe.ui.custom_button.IndieButton
        android:id="@+id/btLogin"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/loginButtonWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/loginButtonHeight"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/paddingXXLarge"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button_white_shape"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fsXLarge"
        app:font_type="SemiBold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Inside my fragment I use ButterKnife to bind the views:

```java
@BindView(R.id.etEmail)
EditText etEmail;
@BindView(R.id.etPassword)
EditText etPassword;
```

And the only line I use is:

```java
etEmail.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);        
etPassword.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: Add your code, what you have tried

Comment: @VicJordan done!

Comment: @VicJordan I forgot to say that the problem is only on my Galaxy S8 with Android 8.0. On my other phone, Galaxy S7 Edge with Android 7.0, everything is OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!
The below line inside my EditText style.xml was the one which messed up the whole thing.

```xml
<item name="android:textSelectHandle">@color/transparent</item>
```

But I still have a problem with the popup menu which is "cropped" :

[image]